# Selecting from a table based on a combination of attributes from a html form with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have an HTML form that has five different categories.

1. Spatula name.
2. Type ('Food', 'Drugs', 'Paints', 'Plaster').
3. Size (measured in cm).
4. Colour.
5. Price.

How would I implement the PHP to select based on one or a combination of these? That would only search through one table.

Comment: You would have to have 5 params that bring with them the values the user enters in the html, from there a HTTP request is made, and the params selected by the user are passed to the php script

Comment: @Cristian how would i do that as they are each different columns.

Comment: by using sql queries

Comment: or depending on whatever DBMS you're using

Comment: @Cristian I'm using Mysql and I'm quite new to this. Is there something like and/or ?